# Learning to work with BackgroundWorkers

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I'm learning to Work with the BackgroundWorker class and created a simple program to play with.

I put together a very simple application. It has two .xamls, one is the MainWindow and the other is WorkersRunningUI. The MainWindow has a single button and the WorkersRunningUI has a single label. Then there is the Worker.cs class, which houses all of the BackgroundWorker logic.

My Goal:
When I click the button on the MainWindow, I would like the MainWindow to be hidden and the WorkersRunningUI to appear. This will then launch a BackgroundWorker who will do some processing (increment
a counter), update the label in WorkersRunningUI with the counter as it increments, hide the WorkersRunningUI once its complete and show the MainWindow again.

Results:
When I click the button, it looks like the UI thread gets locked up. I can see the DoWork method incrementing the counter via Command Line but the UI is locked up until it's complete. My research indicates
that doing anything with the UI inside of DoWork is a big No-No, and you need to use ProgressChanged for UI updates. I've done that, so I'm not sure what is the reason for the UI continuing to lock up on me. I can see the WorkerRunningUI display, but it appears to be hanging.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BW_TEST.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Second Imp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="301,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btn_SecondImpClick"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public WorkerRunningUI workerUI;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void btn_SecondImpClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Worker workerObject = new Worker();
        this.Hide(); // hide main application
        workerObject.workerUI.Show();
        workerObject.launchWorker(1);
        workerObject.workerUI.Hide();
        this.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

WorkerRunningUI.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BW_TEST.WorkerRunningUI"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WorkerRunningUI" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid Margin="0,0,-8,-1" Height="271" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300">
    <Label Name="WorkerLabel" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103"/>
</Grid>
```

WorkerRunningUI.xaml.cs

```
public partial class WorkerRunningUI : Window
{
    public WorkerRunningUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Worker.cs

```
// This class is responsible for the BackgroundWorker logic
class Worker
{
    public BackgroundWorker worker;
    public WorkerRunningUI workerUI;

    public Worker()
    {
        this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.workerUI = new WorkerRunningUI();
        this.worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Progress Changed: " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
        this.workerUI.WorkerLabel.Content = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RunWorkerCompleted: " + e.Result);
        this.workerUI.Hide(); // hide loading app
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int value = (int)e.Argument;

        while (value < 1000)
        {
            this.worker.ReportProgress(value);
            value++;
        }

        e.Result = value;
    }

    public void launchWorker(int i)
    {
        this.worker.RunWorkerAsync(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have two separate instances of `WorkerRunningUI`, one that is created and displayed in your initial button click and another that is created in the worker class that is not explicitly shown.  Can you see both running UI windows or just the first one?

Comment: Sorry about that @leetibbett. The instance of WorkerRunningUI on the button click was some code that I was testing. I've edited it to only use the Worker class instance. The WorkerRunningUI can be seen, but appears to be locked up/hanging until DoWork is complete.

Comment: Your worker does not do any real work, can't take more than a handful of microseconds.  It gives the UI thread a pretty big headache though, it has to add a thousand lines to the VS output window.  Which is not fast, the process interop is expensive and the scrolling is quite expensive.  Also the reason that .NET programmers think that exceptions are too expensive.  Write real code and you'll get a real result.

Comment: Your worker finishes so fast that the background worker is done before the events are handled and the console is written.  All the slowness is the UI handling the events.  If you put a Thread.Sleep(100) into the `while (value < 1000)` loop to simulate some kind of work, you'll see that the UI is responsive and your worker continues to run asynchronously.  Also move the `workerObject.workerUI.Hide();
        this.Show();` into the Worker so it can close them itself when complete.

Comment: @leetibbett You were absolutely right. Adding a Thread.Sleep(100) in the loop and I was able to see that the UI is responding as expected. I moved the workerUI.Hide() into RunWorkerCompleted() but not this.Show() because 'this' in this instance is the Worker class, not the MainWindow. Can I manipulate the MainWindow from the Worker class? If so, how?

Comment: By injecting it through a property/constructor, or raising an event that the main window handles, a message system, etc.  I don't know your  real scenario but if you don't want your user working in the main window while the child is open, I would recommend that you open the child window with [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of doing all the hiding/showing yourself.

Comment: The child window is essentially a "Progress Loading" screen that will give updates on a SQL command that's being run by the BackgroundWorker. The MainWindow will be disabled while the query executes, and only will become available again once it is complete. Passing the MainWindow through the Constructor is an interesting concept, thank you for that.